# How does Haskell manage its memory?

Tags: haskell, memory-management, functional-programming, ghc

So, we know that for most languages, throughout a program's execution:

- Global variables are stored in static memory.
- Local variables are stored in the stack memory.
- Arbitrarily-changing variables are stored in the heap.

What about Haskell? All I know is that it is lazy. How does that translate into this context?

Comment: Well a lot of (high-level) languages keep it open how memory management is implemented. But for GHC, this [wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Memory_Management) might be a start.

Comment: As a zeroth-order approximation you'd have to say that _everything is on the heap_ in Haskell, but more practically we can assume that the compiler will decide to put any variable whereever it's deemed best for performance. Quite often it will also eliminate variables _entirely_, or introduce new ones. All that the language specifies is that you'll get the right results in the end...

Comment: Don't forget that static/stack/heap memory does not really exist on its own. At the lower level, we only have RAM (including virtual memory). Then the OS may reserve a portion of the address space for the "stack", allow processes to request more stack (e.g. `sbrk`) or heap (`mmap`), and pre-allocating a static portion when the executable is loaded. The the language runtime system can, on top of this, use garbage collection. Some variants of GC further divide the memory into generations or from-space/to-space (for copying GCs). These are further abstractions, usually implemented in the "heap"

Comment: *Haskell* doesn't say anything about memory management. A particular *implementation* of Haskell makes those decisions.